# Dispatch link error

Tags: objective-c, linker, clang, grand-central-dispatch

I used to be able to compile an async Hello World-style program, but after upgrading to Yosemite/Xcode 6, I get a link error. How can I tweak my make instructions to successfully link to the dispatch library?

Code:

https://github.com/mcandre/parhello/tree/master/objc

Trace:

```
$ make
mkdir -p bin/
clang -Wall -Wextra -Wmost -Weverything -framework Foundation -lobjc  -fblocks -ldispatch -lBlocksRuntime -o bin/parhello ParHello.m
ld: library not found for -ldispatch
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [bin/parhello] Error 1
```

System:

```
$ specs clang xcode os
Specs:

specs 0.12
https://github.com/mcandre/specs#readme

clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix

xcodebuild -version
Xcode 6.1
Build version 6A1052d

system_profiler SPSoftwareDataType | grep 'System Version'
System Version: OS X 10.10.1 (14B25)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing those errors is because the Makefile is meant for a Linux system and you're building under MacOS.

If I change line 4 in your Makefile from:

```
LINK_OPTIONS=-ldispatch -lBlocksRuntime
```

to

```
LINK_OPTIONS=
```

The target compiles and executes with output that looks like:

```
[parhello/objc]:;make
mkdir -p bin/
clang -Wall -Wextra -Wmost -Weverything -framework Foundation -lobjc  -fblocks  -o bin/parhello ParHello.m
bin/parhello
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132933] e
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132934] l
2014-12-02 13:05:10.146 parhello[77009:2132944] !
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132937]  
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132936] o
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132932] H
2014-12-02 13:05:10.145 parhello[77009:2132940] r
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132935] l
2014-12-02 13:05:10.145 parhello[77009:2132942] l
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132939] o
2014-12-02 13:05:10.145 parhello[77009:2132943] d
2014-12-02 13:05:10.144 parhello[77009:2132938] W
```

Comment: Indeed, while I was working on the Linux port, I made a mistake there. Thanks!